# Am I drawing the correct use case diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

I am currently designing a use case diagram for pharmacy system.
Hereby are the actors and their respective use cases.
Customer :

- register
- manage cart
- browse product
- checkout
- check order
- update prescription information

Pharmacist

- view order
- view prescription record
- verify prescription order

Retail Assistant

- view order
- process order
- manage product

Manager

- view order
- view product
- generate sales report

[image: Pharmacy System]

I hope my use case diagram is logical and understandable. Kindly point out my mistakes as there are too many references out there which I do not whether am I right.

Comment: How can we tell without knowing the requiremens?

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I notice is that you listed the pharmacist, retail assistant, and manager as supporting actors instead of primary actors. Generally, if your system has a use case to help an actor achieve their goals (i.e., not the system's goals), then said actor is a primary actor. In this example, I would say that a pharmacist is a primary actor since they need to verify prescription orders using the system.

You don't have a line connecting Retail Assistant to the Process Order use case. You also say that processing an order includes canceling an order; I personally disagree with that (many orders are processed without being canceled), but I can see an argument for order processing including order cancellation.

This is very minor, but the diagram says "*upload* prescription information" whereas your question says "*update* prescription information."

Comment: ahh..I see. So, is there anything I need to change? or I can stick to this and change the thing that you mentioned?

Comment: so i should move my pharmacist to the left, while others on the right?

Comment: I would move all actors to the left and add the line between Retail Assistant and Process Order. UCDs can be a bit subjective/fuzzy at times, though, so don't be afraid to disagree with me.

Comment: I decided to plan retail assistant, pharmacist and customer on the left, while the manager remains on the right since manager didn't really help with other actors but only viewing order and product. make sense?

Comment: I would still put manager on the left. My rule of thumb is that if the system's UI would have a screen for actor X, then actor X is a primary actor. Since the manager can view orders and products, they have at least one screen (probably two); so, they're a primary actor. A supporting actor might be something like PayPal's payment processing system; it helps the system function, but the system does not have a use case to help PayPal achieve PayPal's goals.

Comment: I see....thank you understood!

Comment: primary/secondary actor placement is only a convention, not a law.